# How to bring valus from a window to a Page in WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have an WPF application that has just one Main Windows and a IFrame which I use to open my WPF Pages, there is a page that on click of a button I open a Window that has a grid with some data,

How do I do to bring date from that "Popup" window to my Page?

I already tried to get Parent element from window but it has not any.

Thanks in advance once more!

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure what you want, but let me try.

My MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Teste.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="New Window" Margin="0,220" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Resumed MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace Teste
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
         public MainWindow()
         {
            InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
           myWindow newWindow = new myWindow();
           var child = (TextBlock)newWindow.FindName("txtBlock");

           MessageBox.Show(child.Text);
         }
    }
}
```

myWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Teste.myWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="myWindow" Height="300" Width="300" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" Text="Some Text" Margin="100" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Okay, with that in mind:

1. My project has 2 Windows (MainWindow and myWindow).
2. The MainWindow Button event instantiate myWindow.
3. Variable `child` find a element named `txtBlock` (My TextBlock).
4. Since I know I want to get a TextBlock, `child` also cast the element as `TextBlock`, hence the code: `var child = (TextBlock)newWindow.FindName("txtBlock");`
5. Now that I have a "instance" of the TextBlock, I can use any of its properties. In this case, only for testing purposes, I use the `Text` property and show it's content in a `MessageBox` with the code: `MessageBox.Show(child.Text);`

---

Even if that's not what you're looking for, it can give you a hint. The trick here is the **cast**

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Tico, thanks for the reply, it's almost what I want.
Give me another try to say what I have been trying. Different of you example I have a page inside an IFrame and from that frame I pop up a window, that's window is kind of a quick search of customers which I can chose anyone I want. These customers are displayd in a datagrid and I want to when I give a double click in some client It brings all of his data to my page which is sort of "Parent", Was I clear? I can say that in portuguese as well!

Comment: Sadly it did not. I am in a page, when I click in the button "search customers" it opens a window dialog showing the customers in a grid. From that I cannot at all pass any value to my page because they do not have anything linking them.

Comment: Hm...Could you give me an example?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: From what I understand is: you click the Button go to a Window, select a row/cell from a grid and want to use it at the previous Page?

Comment: I see, I would try to send the data as a parameter or bind it to a property via `relativesource`. Other than that, I could only help by seeing it! Good luck.

Comment: You could access my computer by using skype if you wanted to, anyway that is just an idea. Thanks for you time Tico!